# Include helper in a helper subclass keeping controller context functions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dependency-injection, helper

Actually, this is my problem. I have a rails app with a MainController, a HttpHelper and a ServiceHelper.

**main_controller.rb**

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
    include ServiceHelper
    def my_method
        Service.make_stuff
    end
end
```

**service_helper.rb**

```
module ServiceHelper
    class Service
        include HttpHelper
        def self.make_stuff
            http__foo
        end
    end
end
Service = ServiceHelper::Service
```

**http_helper.rb**

```
module HttpHelper
    def http__foo
        #stuff
        params[:bar].nil?
    end
end
```

If everything work well, this code should tell me if the `:bar` param exist, but I have a problem. Firstly, this code doesn't work, it tells me that `http__foo` is not defined, certainly because the `include HttpHelper` in Service doesn't work.

My second probleme is that if the include works, there will probably be a problem with the `params` variable. If I call this method (`http__foo`) in the controller, it will be fine, but I call this from a subclass, then I'm not sure it's be reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`make_stuff` is a class method. `http_foo` is an instance method. Hence, when you call `http__foo` from your `make_stuff`, it is like calling `Service.http_foo()` which is not defined. What is defined is `Service.new.http_foo()`.

I don't know what you want to do but in my humble opinion, by watching your code, it does not seem you are really familiar with `Rails MVC concept` and creating a `MainController` (why not use `ApplicationController`?), as well as the way you use your helpers is weird to me. It might be a good idea to restart from scratch.

Comment: Ok, it seems weird to talk about instance for a module, but I finally understood that you was talking of it after the include. I was just trying some tricks, MVC is not a problem, I was just trying to customize helpers, but it's a bad idea ;)

Answer (score 0):

oldergod is correct about the class vs. instance methods issue.  Additionally, params is a method defined in ActionControllor, which is somewhere above the inheritance tree of all your controllers.  The params method will NOT be available in the Service (which is where it ends up when you include HttpHelper in Service), unless you make it a subclass of ActionController or ApplicationController, which would be a little strange since it isn't a controller.